# Second push notification message does not open

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I encountered a problem where the app is closed completely, and I start the first notification it opens where it needs to open, but when I tap the second notification, nothing happens. Notification close and it doesn't land anywhere where it should.

Here's the code in NotificationLaunchIntentProvider where I handle PendingIntent routing.

```
private final SalesForceNotificationRouter notificationRouter;

    public SalesForceNotificationCustomizationManager(AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.notificationRouter = new SalesForceNotificationRouter(appConfig);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public PendingIntent getNotificationPendingIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
        PendingIntent notificationRoute = notificationRouter.getNotificationRoute(context, notificationMessage.url());
        return NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(context, notificationRoute, notificationMessage, true);
    }
```

Here's the code in SalesForceNotificationRouter

```
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    public SalesForceNotificationRouter(AppConfig config) {
        this.appConfig = config;
    }

    public PendingIntent getNotificationRoute(Context context, String url) {
        if (url == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            return pendingIntent(context, intent);
        }

        String path = url.trim();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if (scheme != null && scheme.equalsIgnoreCase(appConfig.getScheme())) {
            Intent intent = DeeplinkActivity.initializeResponseIntent(context, uri);
            return pendingIntent(context, intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ResolverActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(IntentCommand.EXTRA_URL, path);
            intent.putExtra(BaseActivity.EXTRA_CAME_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);
            return pendingIntent(context, intent);
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                randomRequestCode(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
    }

    private int randomRequestCode() {
        return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    }
```

I think before 1 year or less since now, everything was working fine. I wonder where's the problem because i tried to change things like PedingIntent flags, request code, tried opening different activities but nothing helped.

SDK version : 8.0.4 doesnt work in 7.4.2 also (didn't tried lower versions)

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?  Does the OS version of the device impact success?  Please open a support case through your account manager.

Comment: Also, just so we're clear: 1) kill the application, 2) click a notification (works), and 3) leaving the application open click a second notification (nothing happens)

Comment: @BillMote targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: @BillMote yes, that's the sequence

Comment: What do the SDK's logs say?  :)

Comment: What version was previously working?  You stated that neither 7.4.2 nor 8.0.4 work.

Comment: @BillMote https://pastebin.com/0ht08kLz i left some marks on actions

Comment: @BillMote unfortunatelly i cant trace in which version it worked, but we had 7.3.1, 7.2.0, 6.4.0, 6.3.4, 6.3.3

Comment: Something you should do regardless of this issue: remove `redirectForAnalytics` as you're double-reporting the push notification opens.  The helper method for analytics is only required if your application handles the display of the notification.  In this code, you're creating the `PendingIntent` and allowing the SDK to show the notification and thus handle the click even though the action of the click is handed off to you.

Comment: Your paste ends at the notification analytic being tracked.  Please show the remainder of the logs.

Comment: @BillMote logs actually ends in 129 line, I don't receive more logs in logcat after 2nd click

Comment: So, I would recommend you dig into the intents you are launching.  Why? 1) the very first line in the SDK's handling of `open` events is to log the statement you see about logging the open event, 2) the very last line in the SDK's handling of the `open` event is notifying the SDK of the open event and you see that in the logging of behavior found for `notification opened`.  The only code in between is the code to `send()` the intent and `cancel` the notification.

Comment: @BillMote Okay, I managed to revert changes to the 6.3.4 version, but the problem remains, it seems like the problem existed way before then it was reported.

Comment: @BillMote Took a look at my Intents and I found nothing harmful that could make my activity to not open. I did raw implementation of new empty Activity like this PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                randomRequestCode(),
                emptyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        ); but the problem still remains.

Comment: @BillMote I realized that maybe something is wrong with initialization because if the app is started from notification, the following notifications will not work, but If I start the application manually all of the notifications work as expected.

Comment: Version 6.3.4 is almost 2 years old.  We have more than 2 billion installations of this SDK in customer applications.  We have zero reports of what you're seeing.  Please open a support ticket through your account manager so we can better follow up with you.

Comment: @BillMote This problem is not related to Marketing Cloud SDK at all. Just creating my own notification I can replicate the problem, so the fix was to add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to my landing Intent. You can also add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT instead of CLEAR_TASK and it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to Marketing Cloud SDK at all. Just creating my own notification I can replicate the problem, so the fix was to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to my landing `ResolverActivity.class` Intent. You can also add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` instead of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and it works as expected. The only downside is that with clear task, no history will be preserved.